# How can I split time data (h/m/s) in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have data in `#h #m #s` format that I need to convert to columns, but the data does not necessarily contain all units. Example:

```
Case Processing Time (sum)
7m 45s
29s
2m 9s
6h 8s
2h 13m
...
```

I would like this in the format:

```
Case Processing Time (sum)
h    m    s
0    7    45
0    0    29
0    2    9
6    0    8
2   13    0
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Can you share the code you wrote that produces the incorrect result?

Comment: Please don't be discouraged by the downvotes.  Your question is actually pretty interesting and difficult, it's just you haven't provided us the information to help and people react badly to pictures of data instead of copy-able code.  Try to re-ask with the data in plaintext and show some effort at what you have tried already

Comment: As a hint(since this will likely be closed soon) you'll probably need the `re` module and do some lookahead from the numbers  to find the units, and then use `pandas` `apply` statement on that function to do it on the whole column.  But that `re` signature will be tricky.

Comment: The thing is I didnt write the code thats why I asked method, not the code fixing but anyway.

Comment: I edited your question to be more friendly to SO sensibilites.  Hopefully it can lose some down-votes since I think it's actually an interesting question.  Please check to make sure it's actually what you want.

Answer (score 3):

This is a job for regex. Use `pd.Series.extractall`, and then flatten the result:

```
print (df["Case"].str.extractall(r"(?P<H>\d+(?=h))?\s?(?P<M>\d+(?=m))?\s?(?P<S>\d+(?=s))?")
                 .groupby(level=0).first().fillna(0))

   H   M   S
0  0   7  45
1  0   0  29
2  0   2   9
3  6   0   8
4  2  13   0
```

Regex pattern explanation:

```
# ? Matches between zero and one times
# \d+ matches a digit between one and unlimited times
# (?=h) Positive lookahead for literal char h
# \s matches any whitespace
```

Comment: As I expected, that regex signature is not for the faint of heart.